# Why can't I create an ad-hoc wireless network using Intel 4965AGN?

Tags: wireless, drivers, networking, adhoc

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to create a ad-hoc wireless network. I get that my wireless card (INTEL 4965AGN) apparently does not support the ad-hoc mode:

```
$ sudo service network-manager stop
network-manager stop/waiting
$ sudo ip link set wlan0 down 
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc 
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

On Windows instead an ad-hoc network works just fine. I checked [here](http://intellinuxwireless.org/) but it seems like all available drivers should be embedded already.

Does anybody have a similar issue? maybe with another card and there's some way to activate the functionality.

Alternatively, could you please suggest some usb wifi adapter that supports ad-hoc?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 11.10, edit the network and set ipv6 to be ignored:
[image]

Comment: IPv6 is ignored by default I see, don't you think it's more of a driver issue given the messages I get?